# Kotlin TypeToken "Unresolved reference" error

Tags: java, gson, kotlin

I am getting error "Unresolved reference to response" in line number 5,6 and 7. Can you please help me understand the problem?

```
 public class GenericCall {
        public fun genecicCall(functionToBeCalled:String, responseType:String, requestType:String, vararg args:String){
            var request = Class.forName(requestType).newInstance()
            var response = Class.forName(responseType).newInstance()
            var finalType = object : TypeToken<GenericResponse<Class<response>>>(){}.getType()
            var creditresponse: GenericResponse<response>? = AjaxHelper.ajax(Constants.Ajax.ENDPOINT_CREDIT, Constants.Ajax.REQUEST_POST, request, finalType, null)
            return ResponseProcessing.processResponse(creditresponse as Any) as response?
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it a typo or are you missing 2 ">" before () in the 5th line?

Comment: one ">" was missing but still after modification, I am getting the same error.

Comment: You've got 3 open "<" on the line 5.  TypeToken<(1.)GenericResponse<(2.)Class<(3.)response>>()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type argument can't be an expression, it should be another type, such as a class, possibly with other generic type arguments. So instead of `Class<response>` (line #5) you should write for example `Class<Foo>` if `Foo` is the static (inferred by the compiler) type of `response`. In your case you probably don't know anything about `response` apart from the fact that it's an instance of `Any`. So you can use `Class<Any>` or `Class<*>`, whichever you prefer. Similarly with `GenericResponse` (line #6).

Also expression cannot appear in the right-hand side of the `as` operator for the same reason (line #7): this operator casts the left-hand side to the *type* specified in the right-hand side. Additionally, your function doesn't seem to return anything, so returning a useful value from it won't work.